# How to cofigure jenkins to stop running failed builds?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We using open source Jenkins 2.107.2 on AWS.
We use Jenkins pipeline for all our apps.
We do not use multi-branch pipelines.

For one of the application, Jenkins job was failing due to the post-deploy test cases failures. Because of that the job is continuously executing the job until it succeeds.Can we configure Jenkins to retry failed builds only 1/2 times.

I saw `https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin`
but this plugin is not supported for pipeline.

Comment: Why is the pipeline continuously executing? Did you implement something to repeat the pipeline in the case of an error?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
 stage('build') { 

    if(!isBuildable){
      //stop build and jump to next stage
      return;
    }
    //do build tasks
  }
```

**isBuildable** variable could be the result of other stages or any value that indicates that it should be built or not.